# Как и где упоминать свободные продукты, которые я использую?

Tags: лицензирование

Для своей системы я много использую свободных продуктов из репозиториев (например через `composer` подтягиваю нужные плагины). Все они в итоге лежат в папке `vendor`. Все они MIT или BSD и подобные. Текст лицензий уже у них указан.

В итоге, я просто могу использовать эти продукты, а текст может оставаться в этих продуктах в папке `vendor` или мне обязательно нужно где-то будет перечислять все эти продукты, перечислять всех авторов продуктов и перечислять тексты всех этих лицензий? Допустим используемых свободные продуктов будет штук 20. Как, где и что теперь нужно обозначить?

Comment: IANAL. // **1.** Когда я в своё время искал ответ на Ваш вопрос, то не нашёл: **а**. Информации, что использование продуктов со свободными лицензиями в непреступных целях может повлечь неприятные юридические последствия; **б**. Существования строгих, обязательных к исполнению правил. Только рекомендации, [**пример**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234526/264224). // По предыдущей ссылке не говорится об автоматической генерации, сам делаю так:

Comment: // **2.** Автоматически генерирую список лицензий зависимостей. Для Python-зависимостей использую [**pip-licenses**](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/), для Node.js/Grunt — [**license-finder**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-license-finder). В опциях, что добавить в сгенерированный файл, выбираю всё, что можно, — авторов, ссылки, описание. Вероятно, для других популярных языков/инструментов есть что-то подобное. // **3.** На главную страницу документации добавляю ссылку на папку со сгенерированными файлами лицензий и кратко объясняю, что в ней.

Comment: // **4.** `Практическое применение` — меня дважды (когда подавал заявки на бесплатное для open source проектов использование BrowserStack и JIRA) просили предоставить лицензии на зависимости — описанное выше в обоих случаях принимающих заявки устроило. // Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если брать современные лицензии BSD и MIT, то в них как правило указываются следующие части:

1. Копирайт
2. Условия
3. Текст лицензии и отказ от ответственности

В условиях написано, что все эти части должны быть доступны в вашем продукте при их использовании, при этом не важно каким образом они будут доступны. Они могут лежать в папке vendor как вы сказали, они могут лежать в других папках, они могут выводиться в экранной форме, быть в документации к программному обеспечению в случае включения кода в двоичный файл.

В большинстве случаев всякие менеджеры пакетов скачивают исходный код вместе с текстом лицензии и ничего дополнительно делать уже не надо.

Comment: Это классно, если это всё, что нужно. Правда Саша Черных пугает меня в комментариях) Еще чуть подожду и дам вознаграждение

Comment: @СергейМишин, есть много разных лицензий и работают они по разному. С BSD и MIT все просто, это простейшие разрешительные лицензии и можно их использовать до тех пор, пока копирайт лежит рядом. А есть свободные лицензии и в частности GNU GPL, который при его использовании требует лицензироваться под ней же и тем самым открыть свой исходный код всем желающим (неплохой такой поворот) - или проще говоря используют копилефт. И вот тут начинаются пляски с добавлением текста лицензии во все, что только можно.

Comment: @СергейМишин в основном вы втретите у себя разрешительные лицензии, при использовании репозиториев плагинов или библиотек, но можно еще это почитать на досуге: https://habr.com/ru/post/243091/